# Configure WRT54 as 'repeater' access point

Tags: router

Existing Topography:
DSL modem hardwired to an ASUS WL-500gP V2 in the residence

The wireless signal is not adquate to reach my home office. I have wired connection via a Powerline AV adapter (netgear) between the 2 buildings so i'm at least able to get a single, wired connection between home and office.

But I'd like try and establish wireless coverage throughout the property - ideally by using an old linksys wrt54g that was orphaned by the new Asus.

I've seen a couple tutes that lead me to think the WRT can be converted/utilized as a pure 'access point' but i wonder the best way to approach this.

Should i be looking to make the WRT a 'repeater' of the existing wireless signal (physically position it at a mid point in the property). Or can I plug the Powerline connection into the older wrt in some fashion that would let me continue to use a wired connection to my primary workstation (via one of the WRT's ports) but wireless of other devices  that are currently out of range.

I'd be willing to risk flashing the WRT over to DD-WRT if that makes either option easier.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flashing it with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) would make this much easier, as it supports repeater mode. However flashing the WRT usually isn't very easy, and may not be possible depending on the model and version you have.

The original Linksys firmware does not support repeater mode, however you could plug it into the powerline adapter and use that to backhaul the internet connection to your main router. The WRT can be used in bridge mode (Ethernet to Wireless without routing).